# threading.Timer() and destruction of instance

Tags: python, destructor, python-multithreading

In interactive python, I did the following experiment:

```
import threading

def hello():
    print "Hello World!"

def greeting():
    t = threading.Timer(5, hello)
    t.start()

greeting()
"Hello World!"  # After 5s delay.
```

I was surprised that the greeting was printed after delay.  I thought leaving scope would have destroyed the Timer instance, but it makes sense that the python's garbage collector would take on that role?

For my needs, the behavior in the above experiment is what I need, but I don't think it guaranteed to always work.  Or will it always work as shown?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to assume that the timer survives.

A `Timer` is derived from `Thread` and a running thread isn't killed in Python just because no references to the thread object exist anymore (of course there always exist references hold by the Python interpreter itself).